# SBT dependencies are present in cache , but it still show the error dependencies not resolved

Tags: sbt

I have build a project on my machine and share the cache to my colleague. He copied the cache on his .ivy_Home/cache and when he tries to build the project , it shows dependencies not resolved exception .

logs are -

> Yo

```
u probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.11;2.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\TEMP.FM.007\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-sql_2.11\2.2.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0/spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\TEMP.FM.007\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.spark\spark-sql_2.11\2.2.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/TEMP.FM.007/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0/spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0/spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.11 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0 (C:\CDE\Mosaic\dcp\build.sbt#L13-18)
[warn]        +- default:dcp_2.11:1.0
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0 (C:\CDE\Mosaic\dcp\build.sbt#L13-18)
[warn]        +- default:dcp_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.11;2.2.0: not found
```

Comment: You should provide more details: project dependencies, what cache exactly have you shared to your colleague and where did he save it. From the resolution log you see where sbt tries to find those missing dependencies. Probably he just put it in the wrong place.

Comment: why the sbt try to get the dependencies from local folder and not cache folder ? How dependencies checking works in SBT ?